# android ProgressDialog multi-thread dialog doesn't appear

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

i'm a new android programmer, here's my question that i can't solve it.

i have 3 classes, MainActivity, Database and ProgressShow.

in class Database, there's a function to copy a big database in assets. and in ProgressShow, it's used to build a ProgressDialog.

but when i start the program, the dialog didn't show, but it did stoped at the break in handler after about several seconds. it seems that the message queue was stucked when copying the big file. but i don't know why. and here's my program, please help me. thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         

        Database database = new Database(this);
        database.CopyBigDatabase(CommonPara.DB_CONTENT_NAME, 
                    CommonPara.DB_CONTENT_PATH + CommonPara.DB_CONTENT_NAME, 
                    CommonPara.DB_CONTENT_COUNT);
    }
}   



public class Database
{
    private Context mContext;

    public Database(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase DbConnection(String file)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;

        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
        {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null);
        }
        else
        {

        }       
        return db;
    }

    public void CopyBigDatabase(final String name, final String dest, final int count)
    { 
        new Thread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {   
                final ProgressShow dialog = new ProgressShow(
                    mContext, "please wait", "wait", ProgressShow.DIALOG_TYPE_BAR,
                    ProgressShow.DIALOG_DEFAULT_MAX);
                dialog.ShowDialog();

                try 
                {   
                    InputStream is;
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                    {
                        is = mContext.getAssets().open(name + "." + 
                            String.format("%03d", i));
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int length;
                        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                        {
                            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                        os.flush();
                        is.close();

                        if(dialog.GetProgress()
                            < ProgressShow.DIALOG_DEFAULT_MAX -1) 
                        {
                            dialog.CloseDialog();
                        }
                    }
                    os.close();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    dialog.CloseDialog();
                }
            }
        }.run();            
    }
}



public class ProgressShow
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null; 

    public static final int DIALOG_TYPE_SPINNER = 0;    
    public static final int DIALOG_TYPE_BAR = 1;    
    public static final int DIALOG_DEFAULT_MAX = 100;
    public static final int DIALOG_DEFAULT_INCREASE = 1;

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler handler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {                
            if(msg.what == 0)
            {                
                dialog.show();                
            }
            else
            {
                dialog.incrementProgressBy(msg.what);
                if(GetProgress() >= GetMax()) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                } 
            }

            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };    


    public ProgressShow(Context context, String title, 
                        String message, int type, int max) 
    {  
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        switch (type) 
        {
            case 0:
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);                
                break;

            case 1:
            default:
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                break;
        }

        dialog.setMax(max);        
        dialog.setTitle(title);  
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setProgress(-dialog.getProgress());

    }    

    public void ShowDialog() 
    {   
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);        
    }  

    public void AddProgress(int increase)
    {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(increase);
        int a = GetProgress();
    }

    public int GetProgress()
    {
        return dialog.getProgress();
    }    

    public void CloseDialog()
    {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(GetMax());    
    }

    public int GetMax()
    {
        return dialog.getMax();
    }

}
```

Comment: i suggest you use asynctask to copy the big data and onPostExecute you show the necessary UI actions.

Comment: This id not good way to show dialogs from other thread. Check ot the AsyncTask class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: i've found a mistake. if(dialog.GetProgress() < ProgressShow.DIALOG_DEFAULT_MAX -1) { dialog.CloseDialog(); } should be if(dialog.GetProgress() < ProgressShow.DIALOG_DEFAULT_MAX -1) { dialog.AddProgress(ProgressShow.DIALOG_DEFAULT_INCREASE); } and then it's ok. now can show the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

The ProgressDialog must be showed in the main thread; you are trying to display it from a separate thread), because the handler is running in the thread where it is created.

Your flow is this: you create a new thread, then create a new ProgressShow in this thread. When creating a new ProgressShow object, you create a new Handler object. This handler is created in the new thread. A progress dialog cannot be displayed from a thread other than main.